# EEVEE crashes while rendering with animation nodes

Tags: rendering, animation-nodes, eevee-render-engine

title speaks for himself.

[blend file](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52176)

Comment: Could be this issue (https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1074) that hasn't been resolved yet.

Comment: Title rarely speaks for itself and in this case doesn't as well. Don't make others to download your file please only to troubleshoot your problem. Elaborate on what you are creating and what you are facing in the result. All crashes usually should be supplied with log from console in order for others to get additional context of the error

Comment: Also see https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded the file and tested it.

It seems to work fine on my computer so this leads me to believe that you may need to upgrade your hardware (dosen't have to be much mine is from 2009).

If you are unable to upgrade your hardware then (assuming your on windows) windows has it so after a program has been running for a certain amount of time it will be closed you can adjust this time [(video on how to fix)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6VW0KgCv4o)

If it is none of those then please provide a clip of what happens when you try to render.

Anyway here is the image [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1IMhf-p0dSBOCRGYTZD-RfJkvBzKktKEb?usp=sharing)

Comment: I think a clip is unnessecary because I can easily explain it. I start the rendering and after a random amout of frames (1-10) blender closes. I will test your proived solutions soon.

Comment: Have you tried  downloading the latest version of your  drivers and blender as 2.8 was recently released full version.

Comment: @MarcTeuber The crashing issue of AN during animation rendering is not resolved yet, see here:https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1032. However, for the time being, you can use this script to render animation: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues/1032#issuecomment-464411779